# Has Google stopped offering it's "Weighted" Analytics sorting filter?

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to better evaluate my user's engagement and came across a feature of Google Analytics that I didn't know about, [Weighted Sort](https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1042020). This is supposed to sort by bounce rate and also time on page, however it appears unselectable in my GA account [image: see screenshot]. Can anyone verify that it is no longer offered? Or do I need to configure it somewhere else? I couldn't find any reference online to this feature being disabled in the new version of Analytics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weighted sort is intended to filter outlier data from the grid view - for example, if you had the following pages (sorted by Bounce Rate) it's obvious that you'll want to pay more attention to items #3 and #5 over the others, even though a descending bounce rate sort would place the low-traffic pages at the top:

```
 #  URI               Hits          Bounce Rate
 1  /example-abc/     3             100%
 2  /example/         1             100%
 3  /popular/         1000          99.98%
 4  /contact/         9             52%
 5  /semi-popular/    552           40%
```

From the [Weighted Sort documentation at Google Analytics Help](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=173542):

> With weighted sort, our system takes into account the number of
>   visits, bringing [rows] with more visits to the top of the list.

With the Bounce Rate column selected, you can switch to Weighted Sort to get a list more like this:

```
 #  URI               Hits          Bounce Rate
 1  /popular/         1000          99.98%
 2  /semi-popular/    552           40%
 3  /contact/         9             52%
 4  /example-abc/     3             100%
 5  /example/         1             100%
```

**Update:** ... and, although it's not listed at Google's help center, you will also need to disable any [Advanced Segments](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=108040) you may be using to filter data in order to enable this feature.

Comment: No matter what I try I can't get the "weighted option" to appear, it is always grayed out. Can you verify that it works for you? Are you in the content>site content> All pages view?

Comment: Yes - from Content > Site Content > All Pages I get the "Weighted" option after I sort on the Bounce Rate column (but only if sorting on Bounce Rate)

Comment: Aha, I had been viewing my data with an advanced segment. Once I turned it off, the weighted option showed up! Thanks.

Comment: if you add the bit about turning of segments to your answer I will accept it. I think your answer is very comprehensive, but wasn't why I couldn't sort by weight. Thanks.

Comment: @Drai Odd that the help documentation made no mention of this limitation - good catch.

Comment: The docs say any percentage-based metric should work, but I only see 'Bounce rate' enabling weighted sort. I'd like to sort by 'Abandonment rate for a goal', but no luck there. I'm not using any advanced segments, but I am using browser as a dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the data by Bounce rate to enable the greyed out "Wighted sort"
By default it is sorted by pageviews.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom report firstly with less columns and have pageviews column next to bounce rate column.